# Calculating values in list in python

Tags: python, django

Hello I get values from an external `API` call. I need to put these values inside one array with 7 indices, don't know why it doesn't work. I get a nice error from `Django` which says :

Catching classes that do not inherit from `BaseException` is not allowed

I want to calc each element to a var like that:

```
val[0] += 2509
val[1] += 19
```

I set it up like this:

```
val = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

            for item in post_values:
                if item['value']:
                    try:
                        val[i] += item['value']
                    except float:
                        val[i] += 0
                post_value.append(item['value'])
                complete += item['value']
                i += 1
```

These are the Values I get:

```
2509
19
1448
1324
1434
2971
0
15
46
45
9
722
398
218
18
419
344
```

Comment: `except float`. float is not an exception.

Comment: if i get rid of that the error is 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write `except float`.

The `except` clause of the `try` statement is meant to catch an exception. That's why you get that error.

If you want to catch the case of when the variable `item['value']` is not a `float`, you should do `val[i] += float(item['value'])`, and the exception to catch in that case is `ValueError`:

```
for item in post_values:
    if item['value']:
        try:
            val[i] += float(item['value'])
        except ValueError:
            val[i] += 0
    post_value.append(item['value'])
    complete += item['value']
    i += 1
```

Comment: hmm still get 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: looking at the trace of that error you get, which line produces that error?

Comment: val[i] += float(item['value'])

Comment: try printing the variable `item` before that error happens. probably `post_values` is an array of float, and not an array of dictionaries with a `'value'` key.

Comment: Posted it above:  This 1584. something shouldn't be there i don't know where it is comming from

Comment: Found the error, the val variable was used later. thats why it started to act up, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subscript the float. Instead of `{'value': some_number}` you have `1584.5714285714287` which is not a dictionary.

You can modify the code to execute `try` when calling `item["value"]`, this way when `1584` comes up instead of a dictionary, the code will execute the `except` part.